# VBA user defined type not defined (only sometimes)

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel Workbook **sometimes** I get the following error:

> vba user defined type not defined

I do know that this typically means that there is some type in the code excel(VBA) does not know .

The strange thing is that the code runs perfectly fine and this doesn't happen while compiling.

This error randomly occures sometimes at all methods of the Application.Calculate family and on F9 keypress. 
Not always but sometimes.

The same behavior has a vbe error message with this description:

> visual basic module contains a syntax error

When I click debug it lands on `application.calculate(full)` and if I continue the code (with F5) it continues without errors.

EDIT: 
Sometimes when I copy this function to another workbook it gets affected by the Userdefined type error:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function MergeAreaValue(rng As Range) As String
On Error Resume Next

If rng.MergeCells = True Then
    MergeAreaValue = rng.MergeArea.Cells(1).Value2
Else
    MergeAreaValue = rng.Value2
End If

End Function
```

The function gets the value from a merged area.

EDIT2: 
I've the userdefined type error always occures at calculation but doesn't break it. The workbook still calculates normal .. the message is just annoying.

Comment: Is the offending type defined in your own code, or in a library? If the latter, have you checked whether it's included in Tools/References?

Comment: well i should note that this error does not point me to a declaration. (Like i think it should do) 
The Workbook contains quite a lot of code. But the only (not standard) external references are Microsoft Scripting Runtime. and Microsoft XML

Comment: Do you happen to have similar variables that are public else where?

Comment: @DougCoats i've just fund a procedure related to this error. Will Update the main Question in a sec

Comment: Are you using `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, and does your VBA code compile successfully?

Comment: A similar problem came up a few days ago with the `Workbook` object and fully qualifying that with `Excel.` solved it. Perhaps the same would help, here? `rng as Excel.Range` for the code sample you included...

Comment: @Smandoli Yes and Yes !

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks i will try this on Monday.

Comment: @CindyMeister Okay i just tried this. It doesn't seem to solve the issue 
More details in Main Question edit.

Answer (score 0):

It seems me that ***"sometimes"*** is the keyword. Try to decompile file. With [this](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=Orlando+VBA+Decompiler), for example.

Many years I use it without any problems, but with benefits only :)
Excel have no internal decompiler as Access /decompile.
Don't forget to backup by yourself, not the tool only :)
.